# Unordered ACK answer

Tags: tcp, tcp-ip

is there any body knows ; how a server answers to client what if they send first packet as  non-syn or the server finish the connection and wait for a new connection instead of getting an ACK or push packet etc.

Comment: By definition, a TCP connection starts with a SYN. You can not "finish a connection" that has not started. Neither can you receive an ACK belonging to a non-started connection: the packet is obviously illegitimate and will be ignored.

Comment: But it does not live forever. I am asking that after a whiler when the server or firewall finish the connection what it tells to client ?

Comment: You should really be more precise in your question about the context. From what I understand, the question is about an ACK frame that comes out of nowhere since you mention ACK as the **first** packet sent by a client to a server. In that case, this would be an illegitimate packet: see roaima's answer. On the other hand, if that ACK is a duplicated ACK from a previous TCP session (now finished), or if that ACK is for an existing session, this is a completely different story and you should reword your question.

Answer (score 4):

You've tagged with [tcp](/questions/tagged/tcp) so I assume this is what you're referencing.

If a server receives an unexpected packet, the protocol requires the server to send RST. In practice, a firewall may simply drop the packet (discard it) so the server never receives it, and will therefore never send its RST.

I don't understand the second part of your question.

Comment: IMHO you answered both parts of the question at once. I believe OP wants to know if the rogue packet gets discarded or buffered.

Comment: Ok yes you are correct , but firewalls keep sessions for a while. I was just trying to ask what if client try to connect after a while that is more then the firewall's keep alive time out. So firewall will be finished the session and won't accept the ACK or push or etc. How does it tells to client to start a new connection

Comment: @FireBall the firewall doesn't tell the client to start a new session.

Comment: That is a really bad situtaiton , then clients goes on send ack / push  packets and waits for an answer while dropping it's packets ?

Comment: @FireBall the client will eventually receive a TCP timeout. If you want more than that you need either to configure the firewall either to send RST instead of dropping invalid data, or to have a longer timeout, or to configure the client to use keep-alive packets to that the timeout doesn't ever trigger.